# How to get a request for multiple buy order prices on STEAM MARKET by manipulating the url?

Tags: html, json, url, steam, steam-web-api

I understand there is a way to render a steam market search url into a JSON by adding "/render/" to the url and some other parameters in the end that will give you up to 100 market listings per request like this:

https://steamcommunity.com/market/search/render/?q=&category_730_ItemSet%5B%5D=any&category_730_ProPlayer%5B%5D=any&category_730_StickerCapsule%5B%5D=any&category_730_TournamentTeam%5B%5D=any&category_730_Weapon%5B%5D=any&category_730_Exterior%5B%5D=tag_WearCategory0&category_730_Quality%5B%5D=tag_normal&category_730_Rarity%5B%5D=tag_Rarity_Ancient_Weapon&appid=730&norender=1&start=0&count=100

This will give me names, prices, conditions and other data from the listings, but will not give me the buy order price.

I wanted to find a way to get the highest buy order prices for those listings in the same way, by getting a batch instead of having to go one by one, which would take quite a while because Steam limits how many requests you can get in a given timeframe. I still haven't found a way to manipulate the url to do this.

Does anybody know how to request buy order prices for multiple listings at once? If there exists a list of steam url parameters hanging around the internet somewhere a link would also be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.